# Qt Creator デザインモードで相対的な配置をしたい

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Qt Creator で `hoge.ui.qml` を作成、以下のような構成にエレメントを配置しました。

```
item1 (Item)
┗sliderHorizontal1 (Slider)
┗button1 (Button)
```

この際、`sliderHorizontal1` と `button1` は親となる `item1` の上下一杯を占有したいので、上下にアンカーを設定し、ターゲットに `parent` を指定の上、Margin を `0` にしました。
この試みは成功しましたが左右の配置に問題があります。

`sliderHorizontal1` は親の左側 75% を占有、`button1` は残りの 25% を占有したいので、Margin に `100` を入力、 (`item1` の既定サイズはどうやら 400x400 となるようで、これで少なくともエディタ上では右側 1/4 が空きます) 続いて `button1` の左アンカーを `parent` から `sliderHorizontal1` に変更しました。ちなみに `item1` は親エレメントで `anchors.fill: parent` と指定しています。

これで試したところ、`sliderHorizontal1` は `button1` と 3:1 の比になってくれません(ボタンが異様に狭くなる)。おそらく Margin が絶対座標なのだろうと推測しますが、それでは相対座標、ここでいう親に対する 75% といった設定を行うにはどうすればよいでしょうか?

環境は下記の通りです。

- Qt Creator 4.0.1 (Linux版)
- Qt 5.6.1
- QtQuick 2.4
- QtQuick.Controls 1.5

どうかご教示よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `hoge.ui.qml` を `hoge.qml` にリネームして、エディタ上で `parent.width * 0.75` と設定することで一応は対処できました。おそらく正しい方法ではないと思いますので、引き続きご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

すでにご存じの内容もあるかもしれませんので、そのあたりはご了承ください。

まず、*.ui.qmlは以下のようなファイル構成（2つセット）で使う事が想定されています。

- Hoge.qml：ui.qmlファイル専用のロジックを書く
- HogeForm.ui.qml：デザイナで編集

単純にデザインモードを使用したいだけなら、hoge.qml単独でも構いません。
ただし、見た目の無いエレメント（例えばListModelなど）を配置すると親子関係などを編集するツリーで変な挙動をするかもしれません。

で、私が作るなら以下のような感じです。参考にしてみてください。

```
//Hoge.qml
import QtQuick 2.4

HogeForm {
}
```

```
//HogeForm.ui.qml
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

RowLayout {
    width: 400
    height: 50
    property alias sliderHorizontal: sliderHorizontal
    property alias button: button

    Slider {
        id: sliderHorizontal
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width * 0.75
    }

    Button {
        id: button
        text: qsTr("Button")
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
}
```

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます。私のやりたかったことは、まさに `Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width * 0.75` のところです。これをデザインモードでどう設定するかわからず、結局テキストエディタで弄ってしまいました。

Comment: デザインモードでスライダーを選択して、右側のレイアウトタブの推奨サイズのエディットボックス内の左辺りに○印があると思います。その○印をクリックすると「Set Binding」があるので、それを選んでバインドィングの式を書きます。